# Check Item Existence in RabbitMQ

Tags: service, rabbitmq

I have a distributed publisher service, which puts items in RabbitMQ. I want to avoid putting duplicate items into a queue in RabbitMQ.

Is there anyway that I check the existence of an item in RabbitMQ before putting a new item in?

Comment: Short answer: no. Long answer: use a database, not a message queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RabbitMQ queues implementation do not allow to check for their content.

Nevertheless, if what you are after is message de-duplication you can check [this plugin](https://github.com/noxdafox/rabbitmq-message-deduplication).